# How can we implement SCORM into our website

Tags: php, xml, joomla, scorm, scorm2004

I have to implement `SCORM` concept in one of my project. But i dont know about `SCORM`, so i need a help from you guys.

**Concept:**

- Create a `SCORM` file with videos,audios,pdf.
- I have to upload this SCORM file into y website.
- While uploading i have get all the above datas (videos,audios, PDFs) from that SCORM file and save it to database.
- Then i have to display all datas (videos,audios, PDFs) to users.

But i don't know about `SCORM`. Also i referred in Google but i didn't get any solutions . So please help me guys to implement this functionality.

You guys have any sample `SCORM` file please attached here. Because i have to refer the file.

If any useful answers really appreciated.

Comment: What is the version of SCORM? 1.2 or 2004 4th Edition?

Comment: Any version of SCORM. But i don't know how to implement. Can you please explain what is SCORM..

Comment: SCORM stands for Sharable Content Object Reference Model. I suggest you reading the documents at http://www.adlnet.org. There is huge documentation for all the aspects of SCORM.

Comment: Thanks Zafer, I ll go through this document.